# Return all results in aggregate if match query parameter is null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

My Aggregate query:

```
const categoryId = req.query.categoryId
const results = await Question.aggregate([
            {
                $match:{
                    $and : [
                        { category : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(categoryId) },
                        { category : {$ne : null} }
                    ]
                }
            },{
                $lookup: {
                    from: "answer",
                    let: { questionId: "$_id" },
                    pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$questionId", "$questionId"] } } }],
                    as: "answerCount"
                }
            },{ $addFields: { answerCount: { $size: "$answerCount" }}}, {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "users",
                    let : {id : "$creator"},
                    as : "creator",
                    pipeline : [
                        {$match : {$expr : {$eq: ["$$id","$_id"]}}},
                        {$project : {name : 1, profilePhoto : 1}}
                    ]
                }
            }, {$unwind: "$creator"},{
                $lookup: {
                    from: "categories",
                    let : { id: "$category" },
                    as : "category",
                    pipeline: [
                        { $match : { $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$id"] } }},
                        { $project: { name: 1}}
                    ]
                }
            }, {$unwind : "$category"},{
                $unset: ["createdAt", "updatedAt", "__v"]
            }
        ])
```

Now using `$match` query I fetch only the *Questions* belonging to a specific category. What I want to do is if the `categoryId` is `null`, it should return all the results. Right now it returns an empty array. How do i go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```js
const categoryId = req.query.categoryId

let conditions = {
  // You can also have some default condition that always results true
};

if (categoryId) {
  conditions = {
    "category": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(categoryId)
    // More conditions in future...
  }
}

const results = await Question.aggregate([
  {
    $match: conditions
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "answer",
      let: { questionId: "$_id" },
      pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$questionId", "$questionId"] } } }],
      as: "answerCount"
    }
  },
  { $addFields: { answerCount: { $size: "$answerCount" } } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      let: { id: "$creator" },
      as: "creator",
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$id", "$_id"] } } },
        { $project: { name: 1, profilePhoto: 1 } }
      ]
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$creator" },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "categories",
      let: { id: "$category" },
      as: "category",
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$id"] } } },
        { $project: { name: 1 } }
      ]
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$category" },
  {
    $unset: ["createdAt", "updatedAt", "__v"]
  }
]);
```

also read about `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` property in $unwind operator if required.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/